# How to debug your add-in in APS design automation (Autodesk Platform Services)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

Currently im working on Autodesk Platform Services
im unable to debug inventor add-in in aps. How can i debug in cloud.

How to start debugger in add-in to forge side.
Please refer me any solution regarding this issue.

Thank you
Archana

Comment: provide some screenshots and examples

Answer (score 1):

We have a lot of blog posts about this topic. I'm going to leave them here.

The main one I would say is: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-inventor-vs-template-local-debug

But also one of my teammates writes about how to use Inventor Design Automation and here is the collection of blogs:

https://aps.autodesk.com/apis-and-services/design-automation-api-inventor